# Trying to match rows based on matching timestamps in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, timestamp

so I am trying to understand how I can match up the values of two columns based on matching timestamps when the timestamps are not in the same format. I believe this has to do with getting both columns into the same date-time object, but one of the columns has the time stamps components in multiple columns, so I am a bit confused here. I am working in python. I will explain further here.

I have this timestamped data, we will call dataframe A:

```
   timestamp     value_A
-------------------------
 5/3/16 8:00          64
 5/3/16 9:00          74
5/3/16 10:00          54
5/3/16 11:00          34
5/3/16 12:00          26
5/3/16 13:00          42
5/3/16 14:00          44
5/3/16 15:00          14
5/3/16 16:00          65
5/3/16 19:00          36
5/3/16 20:00          32
5/3/16 23:00          32
...
```

Now, here is timestamped dataframe B:

```
Month   Day   Hour    value_B
------------------------------
    5     3      8         35
    5     3      9         44
    5     3     10         22
    5     3     11         25
    5     3     12         75 
    5     3     13         64
    5     3     14         43
    5     3     15         44
    5     3     16         26
    5     3     17         22 
    5     3     18         35 
    5     3     19         36 
    5     3     20         32
    5     3     21         26
    5     3     22         44 
    5     3     23         22 
...
```

constructors:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': ['5/3/16 8:00', '5/3/16 9:00', '5/3/16 10:00', '5/3/16 11:00', 
                                  '5/3/16 12:00', '5/3/16 13:00', '5/3/16 14:00', '5/3/16 15:00', 
                                  '5/3/16 16:00', '5/3/16 19:00', '5/3/16 20:00', '5/3/16 23:00'], 
                    'value_A': [64, 74, 54, 34, 26, 42, 44, 14, 65, 36, 32, 32]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Month': [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
                    'Day': [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
                    'Hour': [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
                    'value_B': [35, 44, 22, 25, 75, 64, 43, 44, 26, 22, 35, 36, 32, 26, 44, 22]})
```

Now, while these two dataframes look similar, they are still quite different, mainly because dataframe A has the timestamp in one column, and dataframe B has the time and date across three columns. Also, notice that there are skipped timestamp entries in dataframe A, and so dataframe B has more rows. What I want to do is match up the rows by timestamp and create a new dataframe with columns for both value_A and value_B, forgetting the value_B rows in dataframe_B that do not have a corresponding timestamp with dataframe A. And so here is the dataframe I want to produce dataframe C:

```
   timestamp     value_A      value_B
--------------------------------------  
 5/3/16 8:00          64           35    
 5/3/16 9:00          74           44
5/3/16 10:00          54           22
5/3/16 11:00          34           25
5/3/16 12:00          26           75
5/3/16 13:00          42           64
5/3/16 14:00          44           43
5/3/16 15:00          14           44
5/3/16 16:00          65           26
5/3/16 19:00          36           36
5/3/16 20:00          32           32
5/3/16 23:00          32           22
```

I am confused about how to work out the logic so that a timestamp can be pieced together from my Month, Day, and Hour columns, and also how to indicate that I want rows without a matching timestamp to be omitted. How can I match up these two dataframes into dataframe C so that the timestamped rows are matched up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the values of "Month", "Day", "Hour" columns to list of lists and then using list comprehension, format each sublist to the correct datetime format and assign the final list of strings to a new `timestamp` column. Then convert both `timestamp` columns to datetimes (actually this step is not needed for this exercise but I'm assuming you'll need it later).

Finally merge `df1` to `df2` on `timestamp` from the left side:

```
df2['timestamp'] = ['{}/{}/16 {}:00'.format(*lst) for lst in df2.loc[:, 'Month':'Hour'].to_numpy().tolist()]
df2['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['timestamp'])
df1['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['timestamp'])
df3 = df1.merge(df2[['timestamp','value_B']], on='timestamp', how='left')
```

Output:

```
             timestamp  value_A  value_B
0  2016-05-03 08:00:00       64       35
1  2016-05-03 09:00:00       74       44
2  2016-05-03 10:00:00       54       22
3  2016-05-03 11:00:00       34       25
4  2016-05-03 12:00:00       26       75
5  2016-05-03 13:00:00       42       64
6  2016-05-03 14:00:00       44       43
7  2016-05-03 15:00:00       14       44
8  2016-05-03 16:00:00       65       26
9  2016-05-03 19:00:00       36       36
10 2016-05-03 20:00:00       32       32
11 2016-05-03 23:00:00       32       22
```

Comment: I do have a question though about how to use this code for the specific circumstance of when the timestamp entries in dataframe A eventually turn to 2017. From what I see producing a .csv file of `df3`, I see that there are no more `value_B` values to match the 2017 timestamps. I would like the `value_B` values to match all timestamps on the corresponding month and day, but regardless of the year. Can I do this with your code suggestion?

Comment: By this I mean that a value of let's say 55 in dataframe B at let's say 5/25, should be matched to timestamps of both 5/25/16 and also 5/25/17.

Comment: @LostinSpatialAnalysis then you just delete years from both dataframes and do everything else same.

Comment: That is a good idea. I tried doing this and dropped the year from dataframe 1 with `df1['timestamp_dt'] = df1['timestamp_dt'].dt.strftime('%m-%d %H:%M')`. And then I tried deleting the year with `b30['timestamp_dt'] = b30['timestamp_dt'].dt.strftime('%m-%d %H:%M')`, and then running everything the same, but then printing the resulting .csv file, I see that the year 2022 is used, which then suddenly jumps to 2029. I am not sure why this happened.

Comment: @LostinSpatialAnalysis I have no idea why that would happen without looking at your data.